# How to delete a file that exists in the SD card in Android?

Tags: android, file, delete-file

I tried these codes to delete a wav file in the sd card from android

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/AutoInsurance_Toolkit/AudioRecorder/1311531953080.wav");

boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

and also in the manifest used the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
```

Please tell me am I missing something here because each time the code gets executed successfully but not deleting the content in SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work assuming you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL permission, the path is correct and the file permission is WORLD_WRITABLE. I'm betting the file was not created as world writable so unless your software created the file you won't be able to delete it.

Comment: I am having the file in the sd card & it is created by the software only.Or is there any other way for the file to be deleted.

Comment: If you created the file yourself then it should work.  Check that the path you are specifying is correct: does file.exists() return true?

Comment: @Femi Can I change the permission to writable using API-8?

Comment: I tried file.setWritabe(true) in API-10 with no luck.

Comment: @Anas: from the spec ***If the user does not have permission to change the access permissions of this abstract pathname the operation will fail.***. Did you check the return value? Do you actually have permission to change it?